# Detect if user closes popup when using gapi.auth.authorize

Tags: javascript

Using the gapi.auth.authorize function, the user can close the popup without clicking any option (no accept or deny button). When this case happens, my callback function doesn't fire, so that I can't handle this case. What's the way to resolve this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: what option did you set to open in new window. I need to open in new window using gapi

Comment: did you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been around for a while, but when I looked into the issue (I want to show a spinner while the google authentication window is open, and hide it if the user decides not to authenticate), and found that gapi is throwing an error `popup_closed_by_user`. There is a two-second delay (which is kind of long, Facebook's is instant) before it is thrown, but it does work. Hooray, Google!

Some sample code (angular 1.x), `prompting` is the attribute to show the spinner:

```
_google_obj.prompting = true;
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(function(googleResponse){
    var token = googleResponse.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    SVC_exec_.post('/q/goog', 1000, { token: token }, 'signing you in through Google', function (response) {
        if (response.code === 'ok') {
            // update the UI
        }
        _google_obj.prompting = false;
    });
}, 
function(error){
    $timeout(function () {
        console.log('user probably closed the google popup window: '+error);
        _google_obj.prompting = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't appear to mention it in any documentation, but `gapi.auth.authorize()` returns the popup `Window`. So you can save the returned `Window` and set an interval or timeout to check `Window.closed`.

Comment: hmmh, it looks like the return value is undefined

Comment: It seems like the return value is a promise :( It is certainly not the popup object.

Answer (score 0):

So you the auth function from Google returns **promise**, not a window. But then you can wrap original window into the function, which will set interval, to check if opened window closed already.

```
// variable to store our deferred object
var authDefer = null;

function auth() {

    // right before the auth call, wrap window.open
    wrap();
    // Call auth
    authDefer = window.gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: ...,
        scope: ...,
        immediate: ...
    }).then(
        // onSuccess,
        // onReject,
        // onNotify
    );
}

function wrap() {
    (function(wrapped) {
        window.open = function() {
            // re-assign the original window.open after one usage
            window.open = wrapped;
            var win = wrapped.apply(this, arguments);
            var i = setInterval(function() {
                if (win.closed) {
                    clearInterval(i);
                    if (authDefer) {
                        authDefer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
            return win;
        };
    })(window.open);
}
```

Taken from one of the thread on Google forums. Really works.

[External link to Source](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/25#issuecomment-76695596)